# C# no overload for method 'GetDouble' takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, overloading

Im trying to use this method called GetDouble but i keep getting the error "no overload for method 'GetDouble' takes 1 arguments" and i have no idea how to fix it.

```
 public static bool GetDouble(string StringToConvert, out double dblOutValue)
    {
        return double.TryParse(StringToConvert, out dblOutValue);
    }
```

im calling it from this method

```
 private bool ReadAndValidatePrice(out double price)
    {
        price = 0.0;

        if (!InputUtility.GetDouble(txtPrice.Text))
        {

        }
    }
```

Any help trying to fix it is appriciated, thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the purpose of the `GetDouble` method?  It's not adding any value to the one thing it does, which is native functionality, so why abstract that one thing?  All it seems to be doing is making the naming less intuitive.  I would expect something called `GetDouble` to get a double.  But it gets a bool instead.  Come to think of it, what is the purpose of `ReadAndValidatePrice`?  It does the same thing, but first clobbers the value it's given.

Comment: The method is sitting right in front of you. It has two arguments. You pass it one. Come on man.

Answer (score 4):

As the error is trying to tell you, `GetDouble()` takes **two** arguments.

The second argument is an `out` parameter, meaning that it will set the variable you pass to it as a result.
When calling it, you must pass a variable with the `out` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few issues here. The first is your GetDouble method. What are you trying to do? If you are trying to just get the double (as the name implies) then it should be more like

```
public static double GetDouble(string StringToConvert)
{
    double dblOutValue;
    double.TryParse(StringToConvert, out dblOutValue);
    return dblOutValue;
}
```

Then look at your ReadandValidatePrice method. With the above change it should be more like:

```
private bool ReadAndValidatePrice(out double price)
{
    price = InputUtility.GetDouble(txtPrice.Text)

    //not sure if the IF statement is needed anymore so it is omitted
}
```

How is that? Where my assumptions completely wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You miss one parameter ,`GetDouble()` takes two parameters. But you have pass one parameter, So you got that error . Now try below method instead of your method .

```
private bool ReadAndValidatePrice(out double price)
    {
        price = 0.0;

        if (!InputUtility.GetDouble(txtPrice.Text, out price ))
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: `price` will need to be marked as an `out` parameter in the method call.

Comment: Sorry , Just miss that. Now i changed that !

Answer (score 0):

Your method should look like follow, because your `GetDouble()` method defines two parameter:

```
private bool ReadAndValidatePrice(out double price)
{
    price = 0.0;

    if (!InputUtility.GetDouble(txtPrice.Text, out price))
    {

    }
}
```